# Short story about possibly the last humans alive struggling to survive in a spaceship, it ends in a baseball stadium in space

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I believe the main characters are a father and son, they and a group of humans are stuck on a spaceship. I don't remember if they are the last humans alive but I do remember there being a sense of hopelessness about getting rescued. They travel around trying to scavenge stuff to survive and losing some members of the crew in the process.

Finally they approach a space station type thing, possibly flying past a bunch of giant heads telling them to turn back. When they land on it, it's an old-fashioned baseball stadium. The father is happy/nostalgic about this, but then he is approached by a groundskeeper who kills him with a sword made of light.

I believe I read it in an anthology something like 7-12 years ago, but I think the story was a lot older than that.